# Error with Geolocation using Parse.com's REST API

Tags: http, curl, parse-platform, push-notification, geolocation

When running the request below I get the following error:

```
{"code":102,"error":"bad type for %!s(MISSING)"}
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Note that the API Key and Id were replaced for security.

```
curl -X POST \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" \
  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d '{
        "where": {
          "user": {
            "$inQuery": {
              "location": {
                "$nearSphere": {
                  "__type": "GeoPoint",
                  "latitude": -23.0,
                  "longitude": -46.0
                },
                "$maxDistanceInMiles": 1.0
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "data": {
          "alert": "Free hotdogs at the Parse concession stand!"
        }
      }' \
  https://api.parse.com/1/push
```

Comment: what about the code?

Comment: What are the extra fields in your Installation class ??

Comment: I get the error:  {"code":102,"error":"bad type for %!s(MISSING)"}